# JOIN not showing all rows

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following query.

```
SELECT WEEK(Review.created)                               AS Week,
       CONCAT(Employee.firstname, ' ', Employee.lastname) AS Name,
       AVG(Rating.scale)                                  AS Average
FROM   employees Employee
       LEFT JOIN reviews Review
         ON Employee.id = Review.reviewee_id
       LEFT JOIN ratings AS Rating
         ON Rating.id = Review.rating_id
WHERE  Employee.id IN ( 71, 72 )
GROUP  BY WEEK(Review.created),
          Employee.id
ORDER  BY WEEK(Review.created),
          Employee.id
```

The results looks like:

```
36, Employee1, 2.9091
37, Employee2, 3.5000
37, Employee1, 3.7143
38, Employee2, 4.2000
38, Employee1, 4.0000
39, Employee2, 2.0000
40, Employee2, 2.8333
40, Employee1, 3.8571
41, Employee1, 2.6667
43, Employee2, 2.5000
43, Employee1, 1.5714
44, Employee2, 3.8333
44, Employee1, 4.4000
45, Employee2, 3.2500
45, Employee1, 4.8571
46, Employee2, 2.1667
46, Employee1, 2.2000
48, Employee2, 2.6667
49, Employee2, 1.4000
49, Employee1, 3.5000
50, Employee2, 2.0000
50, Employee1, 1.5000
51, Employee2, 2.7143
51, Employee1, 2.7500
```

What I need is to return the Employee even if they don't have a rating for that week.

So the first two rows would return

```
36, Employee1, 2.9091
36, Employee2, NULL
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to outer join onto a source containing all the weeks.

Comment: So does this imply I'd need to create a dummy calendar table?

Comment: That would be the most efficient way. You could also do `DISTINCT  WEEK(created) FROM Review` but I wouldn't suggest that.

Comment: I'm getting closer. I found http://www.richnetapps.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/ which explains the basic scenario pretty well.  I've created the calendar table and I'm doing the outer join on calendar and reviews but I get NULL for the employee name.

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly be because of the grouping in the query that your results are being omitted. Try removing the grouping and see what happens

Source

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your group by clause to

```
GROUP BY Employee.id, WEEK(Review.created)
```

as it stands now, if you group first on the review week, any employee which has no reviews for that week will be grouped first on NULL (`week(null) -> null`).

Comment: That won't work. If the data is not there it won't appear in the results.

Comment: Employee records exist regardless of whether they've got ratings in any given week.

Comment: What they want is for `36, Employee2` to appear in the results even though that employee did not get a rating in week 36. Order of `GROUP BY` clauses makes no difference unless this is a weird MySQL thing.